# Delete data comparing two tables

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I have two tables: Table A and Table B. Both tables have a column like a Name, Location, Level.   Table A is an initial table and Table B is the updated version of Table A. That means there will be new data present in Table B. I want to write a query that deletes the data from Table B if data is present in Table A but not in Table B. I don't want to delete the data from Table B if the table has a new row of data.
My approach was like this

```
Delete From TableB Where Exist(
SELECT * FROM dbo.TableB AS TB
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM dbo.TableA as TA)
```

This one deletes the data, but it deletes the data from Table B if it is new inserted data as well. Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are actually using.

Comment: *if data is present in Table A but not in Table B* If data is not present in Table B what will be deleted from Table B?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM TableB
WHERE EXIST(
  SELECT 1
  FROM TableA 
  WHERE TableA.Name = Name AND TableA.Location = Location AND TableA.Level = Level 
)
```

If `TableA` has a primary key, then it's enough to check only this key in `WHERE` condition. Furthermore, if you have this primary key (e.g. it's `Name`), then you can do like this:

```
DELETE FROM TableB
WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM TableA)
```